# Я не понимаю как импортировать модуль sys python. Что я делаю не так?

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, модули

Я делаю все по книге[image: скрин из книги]

Я даже полностью скопировал код из нее (кроме последней строчки)
Но мне не выводит **"We are arguments"**, **"$ pythone3 using_sys.py we are arguments"**, и **"using_sys.py"**

мне выводится только строка **"Аргументы командной строки"** и все, как можно видеть на втором скриншоте[image: вывод]

Если что, весь мой код это:

```
import sys

print('Аргументы командной строки:')
for i in sys.argv:
    print(i)
```

Я серьезно не понимаю как это работает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы все делаете правильно, просто не понимаете, как работает запуск программ из командной строки. Когда вы запускаете свою программу, вы можете передать ей аргументы, а можете и не передавать.

Запуск python `python d:/Python/test.py` не содержит ни одного аргумента, а вот если вы напишите `python d:/Python/test.py we are arguments` то получите желаемое. При этом первым всегда будет выводится имя файла: у автора это `using_sys.py`, а у вас `d:/Python/test.py` и поэтому выводится именно `d:/Python/test.py`. Если переименуете файл, то получите опять же вывод с именем, который вызывается.

То есть если кратко, первая строка "вывода" в книге это то, что вам предлагается набрать в консоли и получить результат.